# KendoUI DateTimePicker (or similar) - make textbox un-editable but allow changing of date/time via provided buttons

Tags: kendo-ui

I have a form which is using DateTimePicker on one of the inputs. I would like the user to be able to select the date/time by using the buttons which KendoUI attaches to the right of the input field, however I don't want the user to free-type into the text field (to save me having to verify formatting or rubbish input).

It is possible to add `readonly` attribute to the input, either in HTML or by calling `.readonly()` method on the DateTimePicker object. This makes the text field un-editable, however it also prevents the click events on the date/time selectors from firing.

So, how do I prevent the user from being able to edit the textbox field manually?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can set the readonly attribute only of the input from which the datepicker was created:

```
<input id="datepicker">
<script>
$("#datepicker").kendoDatePicker().attr("readonly", true);
</script>
```

Here is a live demo: http://jsbin.com/uwayit/1/edit

Comment: Thank you... That works perfectly. I'm not sure what I was doing wrong before, clearly something!

Comment: Note that this solution no longer works in newer versions, the readonly attribute disables the entire control.

Comment: @Pete I'm using the latest KendoUI and it depends on the ordering. If you have an input which has readonly="readonly" and then it is turned into a Kendo DatePicker, the whole thing is readonly. But if you add the readonly attribute after it is setup, then only the input is readonly.